# Cannot register assembly when compiling even though I am running Visual Studio as Administrator

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, registration

I have a significant project that has two projects:

> XXXX.AddIn
>
> XXXX.AdInn.UnitTest

Both projects have Solidworks.Interop.swpublished as references. When I double check the reference properties they are both version 28.1.0.74. Both are marked as Embed Interop Types - false.

When I compile I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Cannot register assembly "C:\Users\erics\source\repos\XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn\XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn\bin\Debug\XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished, Version=27.1.0.72, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89a97bdc5284e6d8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn

Please notice that the error is referencing an older version:

> Version=27.1.0.72

I suspect that there is a NuGet package that is driving the need for an older version of the package.
Why would there be an older package that is trying to get registered?
How would I resolve this?

**EDIT**: I did find a NuGet package that has the 27.1.0.72 version being installed. I am thinking that this questions changes to How do I resolve reference differences between a NuGet package and my application?

Comment: The version number get added to the csproj file when the reference file is added to the project.   It only gets updated when a the compiler recognizes the Net Library has changed and then the project gets updated often the update process fails in the middle and leaves some references updated and other not updated.Then you start getting version numbers errors.I can sometimes fix these error by editing the csproj file and changing the version number.In this case I can understand you project using a newer version of Net than NuGet.But do not understand why the older version is found, not newer.

Comment: Sometime a clean build will resolve issues.  I think I would try doing a clean build of NuGet and see what happens.  The VS compiler dependencies are not very good especially when the Net Version changes.  So the clean build deletes all the intermediate object files which forces the entire project to recompile.  I suspect that in this case the NuGet will not find the file after recompiling.

Comment: @jdweng - How do you do a clean build of Nuget?

Comment: @jdweng- Yep, I see the older version listed three times in the scproj file. There are actually three of them in a row. I think I will play a bit with that file and see what happens.

Comment: The Nuget library can be rebuilt like any other VS project.  Looks like you never rebuilt the Nuget project.

Comment: I do not know why the same reference should appear more than once.   I would go into the Solution Explorer and delete all three.  Save project.  Then add back the reference.  You could do same by editing csproj but It is a little safer using the VS menu.